# Edit Post with a parameter in URL

Tags: editor, wp-redirect

**UPDATE**

It seems that `get_edit_post_link()` is trying to get the Edit url with `?editor`, that doesn't exist but if we set manually the url, it will work:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'edit_post_please');
function edit_post_please()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $id = url_to_postid($url);

        $parts = explode("/", $url);
        $editor = end($parts);
        $editor_link = '/wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $id . '&action=edit';

        if ($editor == '?editor') {
            wp_redirect($editor_link);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone have any suggestions with this idea, please be my guest.

---

I was thinking in a way to make the editors have a quick way to access the current post editor.

I know we can manage this by showing a Link and make some conditionals to show to some users and login in users, but it would be cool to have something like this.

I thought first in something like:

```
add_action('init', 'edit_post_please');
function edit_post_please()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
        $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
        $id = url_to_postid($url);


        $parts = explode("/", $url);
        $editor = end($parts);
        $editor_link = get_edit_post_link($id);

        if ($editor == '?editor') {
            wp_redirect($editor_link);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't think about the security issues or anything else this code does't seem to work at all, I mean it redirects well to Dashboard but not to post I would like to edit.

`$editor_link` have the correct edit url, but seems that this could be a restriction of WP?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code redirects to `/wp-admin/edit.php` is because the [/wp-admin/post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/post.php#L56) checks for a referrer using `wp_get_referer()` before loading.

For this reason, you're best placed using `get_edit_post_link()` to output links to the page.

If you'd like to continue down the path you started, you'll need to satisfy the referrer conditions.